# ssh via multiple hosts

Tags: ssh, multiple-machines

To get to my machine in my office, at the moment I am doing this:

```
me@home:~$ ssh unix.university.com
me@unix:~$ ssh unix.department.univeristy.com
me@unix.department:~$ ssh office-machine.department.university.com
me@office-machine:~$ echo "This is very annoying"
```

Is there an easy way of automating this process, perhaps a single command that I can use at my end?

Comment: related: [How do I SSH to machine A via B in one command?](https://askubuntu.com/q/311447/78103)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the ssh client to execute ssh on the remote machine upon login.

```
ssh -t unix.university.com \
    ssh -t unix.department.univeristy.com \
    ssh -t office-machine.department.university.com
```

(The reason I include `-t` in the invocations is because ssh was giving me errors re: stdin not being a terminal when I tried it on my own machine; your machine may be different.)

When you exit from the last shell, the process will chain-exit, saving you typing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> over and over again.

Comment: Please note : only add "-t" if you just do a login on the remote machine. To start a command on the remote machine, do NOT put them as they can/will corrupt some things (for exemple:   `tar cf - something | ssh  somewhere "cd /path/remote ; tar xf - "`  : could become corrupted if you add `-t` ! See for exemple the wonderful StephaneChazelas's answer http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/151916/why-is-this-binary-file-transfered-over-ssh-t-being-changed/151963#151963 )

Comment: Using -J is more secure than this answer, because you then have the possibility to store all ssh keys on your local computer. The -J option was introduced in openssh version 7.3 as mentioned in the answer from @Miikka

Comment: @ErikSjölund Openssh doesn't allow more than one `-J` option. I think you could do it with multiple `ProxyCommand` options in your config.

Comment: @amphetamachine With `-J` you can specify a comma-separated list of hops to go through. But using `ProxyCommand` with `-W` is still a much better approach than this answer if you happen to be using a version too old to support `-J`.

Answer (score 39):

Yes, there is a great way to do that using ssh ProxyCommand and netcat

Put something like this in your .ssh/config

```
Host *.department.university.com
User me
ForwardAgent yes
ProxyCommand ssh unix.university.com nc %h %p
```

This will log directly into any .department.university.com server using the jump/bastion host unix.university.com.  You may also need a stanza for unix.university.com directly.

Here is a link explaining how it works: http://backdrift.org/transparent-proxy-with-ssh

With this technique, you can now just write

```
ssh unix.department.university.com
```

and it will all appear direct.  Tools like rsync, scp, etc (anything in the ssh stack) will work transparently, as well.

Comment: +1 I use something similar to this to push data from a test network to a prod network through a staging server.

Comment: Yup, this works great!

Comment: Just for the record newer versions of ssh support the `-W` option, you can do something like `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway` instead of depending on nc

Comment: Good  to know! Thx

Comment: works great if the name of the user is the same across machines; if it is different you have to do something like `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p user@gateway`

Comment: If your `%h` is not a fully qualified domain name, then you may have to edit the `etc/hosts` file in your gateway to make the gateway resolve your `%h`.

Comment: pay attention to the keys you are using: the final server still needs to trust the key your client is giving. I had some trouble where the server only trusted the bastion key, and ssh complained about permissions.

Comment: @RiccardoCossu Different user names can be resolved with `ProxyCommand ssh user@gateway nc %h %p` as well.

Answer (score 13):

In OpenSSH 7.3, ssh added the `-J` command line flag and the corresponding `ProxyJump` configuration option to solve exactly this problem.

Give the hosts you wish to ssh through as a comma-separated list to `-J`. For example:

```
ssh -J unix.university.com,unix.department.university.com  \
  office-machine.department.university.com
```

Answer (score 0):

To ssh into server B from server A with the same username

```
Host target
  HostName <serverB_hostname>
  ForwardX11Trusted yes
  LogLevel verbose
  User <username>
  ProxyCommand ssh <username>@<serverA_hostname> -W %h:%p
```