# How to ssh to a server using another server?

Tags: ssh

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [ssh via multiple hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25055/ssh-via-multiple-hosts)

For connecting to *server B* I have to first ssh to *server A*.
What's the command line to access *server B*?

Comment: The second answer is the much better one. Please change the mark!

Answer (score 70, accepted):

If server B is reachable via `ssh` and you only need `ssh` (not direct `scp` or `sftp`), this also works very well:

```
ssh -t $SERVER_A ssh $SERVER_B
```

The `-t` option forces allocation of a pseudo-tty even when running a single command at the other end. This is helpful, since `ssh` needs a pseudo-tty.

Since you're using two nested instances of `ssh`, the escape character in the inner session is <kbd>Enter</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> <kbd>~</kbd> (two tildes). One tilde will send the escape to the first shell.

Comment: Extra tip: you can add the -A argument to passthrough your identity keys. For example: `ssh -A -t $SERVER_A ssh -A $SERVER_B`, great solution for one of those oh-I-can't-access-this-server-directly-but-hey-I-can-reach-it-via-that-server-with-key-auth

Comment: @Zyphrax ssh -A -t <server1> ssh -A <server2> doesn't work for forwarding the private key for me. It says - "Permission denied (publickey)". Am I wrong somewhere?

Comment: @shivshnkr That's strange, it works fine for me. Does your command look like this? `ssh -A -t user@host1.domain.com ssh -A host2.domain.com`. You can also add `user@` to `host2.domain.com`, but I don't think that is necessary.

Comment: Yes, the command is exactly same : ssh -A -t <user>@X1 ssh -A <user>@X2,
If I copy my private key to ~/.ssh/id_rsa in X1 host, it works but not the other way. weird. Do we need some extra configuration in ~/.ssh/config too ?

Comment: I don't believe any extra configuration is necessary. Are you testing (like me) on MacOS?

Comment: @shivshnkr I know what might be the issue with `Permission denied  (publickey)`. In your first part of the command you should take care that you specify a user that exists on the first server. For example: `ssh -A -t  host1-user@host1.domain.com ssh -A host2-user@host2.domain.com`. Both servers should have your local public key in their `authorized_keys` files.

Comment: What if I specify key file using `-i <path-to-key>` ?

Answer (score 21):

There isn't a built-in way in `ssh` to do this, other than to use port forwarding.

However, there is a way that works reasonably well - the `ProxyCommand` setting for ssh.  You can specify that on a per-host basis in `~/.ssh/config` and use it to specify the command to run to connect to the remote ssh port.

I use this on several hosts:

```
host serverB.example.com serverB
  ProxyCommand /usr/bin/ssh serverA.example.com /usr/bin/nc %h %p
```

See the `ssh(1)` manual page for the details, and `nc(1)` from the `netcat` package for the command I am using to forward on the connection.  (You can use anything that makes a TCP connection and passes standard input and output through it, though.)

Comment: I replaced _/usr/bin/nc_ with _ssh_. then after it asks for password of serverA I get this error(s): Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied, please try again.
Permission denied (publickey,password).
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host

Comment: There's no need to replace `nc` there.  See, it's used for creating *a TCP connection from serverA to serverB*, which the `ssh serverB` command then uses to talk SSH.

Comment: Just for the record newer versions of ssh support the `-W` option, you can do something like `ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p gateway` instead of depending on `nc`

Comment: @sr_: You are right! I thought it was mc(midnight commander)

Comment: @UlrichDangel you should add that as an answer to the other question: it is not included there.

Comment: @jasonwryan ok i added an comment, i don't think it's necessary to add an extra answer as the underlying technique (ProxyCommand) is already described

Comment: pay attention to the keys you are using: the final server still needs to trust the key your client is giving. I had some trouble where the server only trusted the bastion key, and ssh complained about permissions.

Comment: In case someone else finds this question while looking for it -- https://askubuntu.com/a/1301548/444824 describes a method that works as of OpenSSH 7.3