# rsync a file from serverC to serverA through serverB

Tags: ssh, rsync

I have computers A, B and C. Every one of them has ssh enabled and I can use `rsync`.

- A can ssh to B
- B can ssh to C
- A can't ssh to C

B has public ssh access, so A can connect B and C can communicate because they are in a vpn and A is not part of it.

I would like to copy some files (and create a cronjob for this) from C to A.

What is a good way to do this?

UPDATE:

I was able to ssh to C  via B as it was explained in the related answers that you suggest me but I was not able to `rsync` through serverB.

- [How to ssh to a server using another server?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/41493/72456)
- [ssh via multiple hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25055/72456)

Consider that B is listening for ssh not on port 22.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works for me:

```
rsync -avzhP -e "ssh -p portB -A user1@serverB ssh" user2@serverC:somedir/ localdir/
```

As reference I read this answer for a similar question:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/21787966/399637

Comment: how can i add a different ssh port for C @res1

Answer (score 2):

If host A can `ssh` into host B, and host B can `ssh` into host C, you can set up your `ssh` client configuration on host A to proxy through B to C.  You can also tell `rsync` to use `ssh` as its transfer protocol (`-e ssh`).  Combine these two things, and you can `ssh` or `rsync` from host A to C by way of B, even in a `cron` job.

Answer (score 0):

I used this command when the servers A, B and C don't have a port other than 22

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -A -J  UserServerB@AddressB' /file-in-ServerA UserServerC@AddresServerC:/path-ServerC
```

But if server B uses s port other than 22 to connect via ssh

```
rsync -azv -e 'ssh -A -J  UserServerB@AddressB:PortB' /file-in-ServerA UserServerC@AddresServerC:/path-ServerC
```