# Matlab crashes after screen session disconnect and reconnect

Tags: ssh, emacs, gnu-screen, matlab

Please forgive the cross-post from matlab answers. This received no response over there. I'll try to go into a bit more detail with this post.

http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/242954-m-shell-exeted-abnormally-with-code-1-when-using-matlab-emacs-with-screen-after-disconnect-and-recon

I run matlab through emacs using matlab-emacs. I do this on a subnode of a cluster computer. I have no problems running emacs with the following set of commands, from my laptop computer.

```
 ssh host1
 ssh node005
 emacs
```

and then in emacs I run *matlab-shell* and matlab runs untill I disconnect my laptop. I would like, however, to be able to disconnect my laptop that I use to run matlab and leave a job running. My non successful attempt has so far been to

```
 ssh host1
 ssh node005
 screen -S sheep
```

and then in screen I run

```
 emacs --daemon
```

and then connect to it with

```
   emacsclient -nc
```

I can run matlab within the emacs client (again with *matlab-shell*). However when I disconnect from the screen session

```
 ctrl-a d
```

and then reconnect

```
 screen -r sheep
 emacsclient -nc
```

And then look at the matlab shell which was already running, I see that my job has teminated and the message

> M-Shell exited abnormally with code 1

Why does matlab crash when I detach this screen session? How does it even know I have detached? Alternatively, perhaps there is a better way I can run matlab in the background (besides vnc, which I am using now but has its own set of bugs). Please let me know if I can provide any other information that might help.

Note that this post follows
[emacsclient connection refused](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226199/emacsclient-connection-refused)
and I am running things as I am essentially in response to that earlier discussion.

edit: there is a description of this set-up allegedly working for someone here: http://sourceforge.net/p/matlab-emacs/mailman/message/31704641/

Answer (score 1):

I found your question because I want to do the same thing (resume a screen session without Matlab crashing), but I have not found a way to do it. Instead, I run a `nohup` job (this is in tcsh):

```
nohup nice matlab -nodisplay -nojvm < list_of_matlab_calls.m >! /dev/null &
```

You can replace `/dev/null` with a log file if you wish. I use `head` so that the log file doesn't become huge if an error message keeps getting written.

```
nohup nice matlab -nodisplay -nojvm < list_of_matlab_calls.m | head -c1M >> log_file.txt &
```

I would rather use screen if possible, so please let us know if you find a way to do it.

Edit: actually it seems I can use Matlab within screen if I start Matlab with a `nohup` (can log out, log in, and resume screen session). I thought I had tried this before and gotten an error.

Comment: Neat! What exactly do you run after attaching to screen to run matlab? Neither `nohup matlab &` nor`nohup matlab < /dev/null &>/dev/null` give me a working matlab interface. Am I missing something?

Comment: Sorry, that was unclear. The lines I quoted are run from the command prompt, without the Matlab interface. To run a Matlab session in screen, I start screen, and at the command prompt run: `nohup nice matlab -nojvm -nosplash` The `nice` is because I am running hours/days-long jobs and want to allow other users' jobs priority. Using this command, I am able to detach my screen and logout without Matlab quitting.

Comment: Thanks for all of this. So this works for running matlab without any interactive display, outside of the emacs client I presume. I still haven't had any luck reconnecting to an interactive matlab session.

Comment: I should note that I am using tcsh, and nohup may differ depending on your shell.