# SCP through multiple hosts

Tags: linux, ssh, scp

[The question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25055/121429) describes how to SSH into a machine that can only be accessed through one or more hosts (that can also be SSH'd into).

Is there an equivalent way of using `scp`? That is, copy a file to my local machine from the far machine (assuming I have password or key access to all machines along the way)?

Comment: The following explanation of how SCP works under the hood might be helpful: https://blogs.oracle.com/janp/entry/how_the_scp_protocol_works

Answer (score 6):

It works the same way as the multi-hop `ssh` if you will use the `ProxyCommand`. The `ProxyCommand` is transparent regardless what you do above that.

```
Host proxy
  Hostname proxy.tld
  User proxy_user
Host target
  Hostname target.tld
  User target_user
  ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p proxy
```

Then running `scp file target:` will copy the file over the proxy to the target.