# How to scp through two intermediate servers to a third-hop server

Tags: scp

I have seen plenty of examples for `scp` through an intermediate server to a second-hop server via `ProxyCommand` operator such that:

```
A:/infile.txt -> B -> C:/outfile.txt
```

Which looks something like the following from A:

```
scp -o 'ProxyCommand ssh userB@hostB nc %h %p' infile.txt userC@hostC:"~/outfile.txt"
```

**My question**, is how to `scp` through two intermediate servers to a third-hop server such that:

```
A:/infile.txt -> B -> C -> D:/outfile.txt
```

I'm looking for a way to do this **using one-liner** similar to the second-hop example provided above ...  but all answers and means are valid if that's not possible.

What I'm trying to do is not the same as [SCP through multiple hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296194/scp-through-multiple-hosts) or variants thereof, which uses /etc/ssh/ssh_config file for setting up aliases.  That's not what I'm wanting to do, I'm looking for a one-liner.  I've also not seen any examples of two or more proxy hosts in between origin and destination, so I believe the question is quite valid.

Comment: @Jakuje, however I will give you credit... that does work, it's just not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The new `openssh` 7.3 provides the switch `-J` which allows you to create your desired one-liner:

```
scp -oProxyJump=userB@hostB,userC@hostC infile.txt userD@hostD:"~/outfile.txt"
```

From [manual page](http://man.openbsd.org/ssh_config):

> **ProxyJump**
>
> Specifies *one or more jump proxies* as `[user@]host[:port]`. Multiple proxies may be *separated by comma characters* and will be visited sequentially. Setting this option will cause ssh(1) to connect to the target host by first making a ssh(1) connection to the specified ProxyJump host and then establishing a TCP forwarding to the ultimate target from there.

Comment: Thanks!   I saw this one earlier today on https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts.  I'm using OpenSSH 7.2p1 and I'm weary of updating to 7.3 out of fear it'll break my Kali install, and I'm studying for the OSCP...  so it's important I don't risk breaking the install until at least after I take the exam.  Do you by any chance know of any other way to do it, using one-liner?  I'm looking for a way prior to OpenSSH 7.3 if possible.

Comment: I was trying similar way with [older openssh in related question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/317491/proxycommand-use-for-multiple-hops-and-prompt-authentication/317644#317644), but it is big mess. I didn't try it, but conceptually it should work

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean... quite messy indeed.  I was hoping for something similar to just specifying either individual -oProxyCommand ' ' switches or nested; I see this example from the link is the nested version, and it's dirty dirty.   I think future-wise, your answer is preferred, so marking as solved.  Thank you!

Comment: That is one of the reasons why the `ProxyJump` option was implemented in OpenSSH. Unless enough people starts using stuff, it is hard to get all the use cases and possible troubles. `ProxyCommand` is good for a lot of stuff in `ssh_config`, but not for ad-hoc forwarding and going through more jumps