# Download a file from two fold login server

Tags: sftp

I have a file, say file.data in on server. How I 'access*' that file is following

1. `ssh institute@12.345.6.789`
2. Enter Password:
3. `ssh username@123.45.67.89`
4. Enter Password:
5. `ls`

I can see file.data here.

How do I download this file into my machine (using sftp, scp, or anything else)?

*By 'access,' I mean I can open using nano or vim.

I am new in this community. I hope I have tried to follow guidelines. Pardon, if I went wrong somewhere.

Comment: You may be able to use scp with a ProxyCommand - see for example [SCP through multiple hosts](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/296194/scp-through-multiple-hosts)

Comment: @steeldriver The suggestion was helpful. I edited ssh config file and now I have to give two word command to access server via sftp, scp or ssh.