# can I access ssh server by using another ssh server as intermediary

Tags: ssh, networking, firewall

I have two servers

```
Server1 -> Static IP1 
Server2 -> Static IP2
```

`Server2`'s firewall allows access only from `Static IP1`

I can connect to `Server1` via ssh from anywhere.

How can I connect to `Server2` from my PC which is behind a dynamic IP via ssh in one step instead of connecting via ssh to `Server1` and then doing another ssh to `Server2` from within `Server1`s shell.

Comment: Or https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/25055/70524

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have OpenSSH 7.3p1 or later, you can tell it to use `server1` as a jump host in a single command:

```
ssh -J server1 server2
```

See [fcbsd](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/86219/fcbsd)’s [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423211/86440) for older versions.

Comment: I just tried and it gives me unknown option -- J
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]

Comment: Ah, yes, you need OpenSSH 7.3p1 or later.

Comment: If you don't have -J you can emulate it using -W and a ProxyCommand directive.

Comment: Also, you can add a host configuration to your `~/.ssh/config` so that connections to server2 always jump through server1. This allows you to use commands like scp and rsync against server2 transparently.

Comment: Adding a host configuration to ~/.ssh/config as per https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25080/275310 was the one that worked for me for my setup and was easier to understand and use. Nonetheless answers here were a very interesting read and helped me understand things better.

Comment: I also tested with updated openssh version and seems to work OK too with the parameter -J

Comment: @DanielPryden Your comments would actually be the best answer for anybody using a distribution which doesn't have 7.3 yet such as Ubuntu LTS.

Answer (score 4):

You need to use [ssh](https://man.openbsd.org/ssh) port forwarding and depending on what you want you either want the `-L` option or the `-R` option.

```
ssh server1 -g -L 2222:server2:22
```

the `-g` allows remote hosts to connect to local forwarded ports, and the `-L` sets up a connection on server1 port 2222 to connect to server2 port 22.

Thus on server1 `ssh localhost -p 2222` will connect you to server2.

If you have problems use `-vvv` that will help give lots of debugging output.

The `-R` sets up a reverse tunnel, so connections on the remote host are forward to the local side.