# How to forward a ssh port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunneling

Curretly I have two machines. One with public ip named `login` and another one are in the same innet named `admin`. Here is what I want:

- When I use `ssh -p 23 login`, I can login to admin via `22` port in `admin`.

I tried two ways:

1. Change `PREROUTING` and `INPUT` chain in `iptables`, forward `23` in login to `22` in admin.
   This didn't work.
2. Use Local forwarding in `login` or reverse forwarding in `admin`.

This way seems to work. however, I can only use `ssh -p 23 localhost` within login computer and failed when I try to connect admin in another computer with `ssh -p 23 login`. I thought this is very close to what I want, but can't figure out how to fix it.

The command I used:

```
# in admin
ssh -N -R 0.0.0.0:23:localhost:22 login
```

or

```
# in login
ssh -N -L 0.0.0.0:23:localhost:22 admin
```

### update

After I changed the port 23 to 222 or any other port, It worked.

It could because 23 a port used by telnet(However this port is not occupied by any program.)

Comment: Just use a `ProxyCommand` or a `JumpHost` like https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/25080/70524 or https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/398015/70524

Comment: @muru Thanks for you suggestion, can you tell me why it doesn't work?

Comment: Probably because the forwarding should be something like `ssh -L 2022:admin:22 -p 23 login` where 2022 is some random port on the local system (`-L <bind_port>:<target_host>:<target_port>`).